# Upon Login or exit, shell freezes for a particular user until they press Ctrl+C

Tags: centos, freeze, tcsh

we are using CentOS 6.9 and one of my users has run into an error where if they login, the screen will be frozen until they press Ctrl+C.  The same thing happens when they exit.  It also happens when I am root, and su - as the troublesome user.  The user uses tcsh but I haven't seen any other user with tcsh suffer this problem

```
[root@boop] # su - troublesome_user
(hangs until terminate)    
^C[troublesome_user@boop ~]$ exit
logout
(hangs until terminate)
^C [root@boop] #
```

I'm most familiar with bash so I checked for .bash_profile and .bash_rc but I now know that tcsh uses a different set of .profile files.  I've looked into their .cshrc files and didn't notice anything strange.

Here's the contents:

```
setenv LC_ALL C
set path = ($path /nfs/bin)
```

Anyone have any clue if there's any feature of tcsh that might cause this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First off, I would check all of the locations where tcsh executes commands from  when it starts.

The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tcsh) has this to say (I have bolded the file locations):

> A login shell begins by executing commands from the system files **/etc/csh.cshrc** and **/etc/csh.login**. It then executes commands from files in the user's home directory: first **~/.tcshrc** (+) or, if ~/.tcshrc is not found, **~/.cshrc**, then **~/.history** (or the value of the **histfile shell variable**), then **~/.login**, and finally **~/.cshdirs** (or the value of the **dirsfile shell variable**) (+). The shell may read /etc/csh.login before instead of after /etc/csh.cshrc, and ~/.login before instead of after ~/.tcshrc or ~/.cshrc and ~/.history, if so compiled; see the version shell variable. (+)

If that doesn't lead you anywhere, I would try the following two things:

- Log in as the offending user and let it hang, switch to a different console and check `w` - that should show you what that user is running.
- `Ctrl+Z` instead of `Ctrl+C` - that should suspend the running process instead of interrupting it. Then `jobs` to see what was suspended.

---

EDIT: As JdeBP pointed out in the comments, you could also set the `-x` and the `-V` options to tcsh in su - although I think you could find the offending thing with `-X`. Something like this:

```
su - troublesome_user -- -X
```

- -x echoes all commands before execution
- -v command input is echoed after history substitution
- -X same as -x but applies even before .tcshrc is processed
- -V same as -v but applies even before .tcshrc is processed

Comment: You forgot the obvious: Instruct `su` to invoke the TENEX C shell with the `-x` and `-V` options.